# "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page." error on Contact us page

Tags: contact-us, contact-form

The error "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page." appears when submitting the contact form.

I just don't know how to handle this. :( In my opinion, this must not even be supposed to happen.
How can I get rid of this error?

[image]

Comment: You should check the code. I once debug in a site that they include a custom code and that caused the error.

Comment: The thing is that the page is generated by module-contact and that module was not touched. There is no code in that module to generate that error.

Comment: I don't say that you modified the code, just an example. You never know what's the issue until you debug the code, or undo what you had done (before the error happen)

Comment: I will try. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Thank you @Jimmy for your suggestion! I found the solution and solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the missing line inside contact page as seen in the page's source code:

[image]

My solution was to overwrite the form.php file of the contact module inside my custom theme so it could generate the line marked in the above picture.

[image]

After that I ran the command: `./magento setup:di:compile`